# Oppo A57 - Unable to detect phone in Ubuntu and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, usb-debugging, ubuntu-18.04, oppo

#### Actual Problem

**Oppo A57** is not getting detected when connected to a laptop running **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** (*Transfer files via USB is enabled*). Not only that i am unable to see that device (*with usb debugging enabled*) in **Android Studio**. USB port in phone is working fine as i can charge the phone.

This problem exists with this device only as any other device (*like Xiaomi Redmi Note 3, Moto G4 Play etc*) is easily detected in both Android Studio and MTP

#### What solutions have i tried

1. I have enabled *Transfer files via USB* and *enabled USB Debugging Mode* in Developer Options
2. I have installed proper device drivers
3. I have also intalled MTP drivers

I have tried lots of solution from Ubuntu's support forums but none seems to work for me. Please help me out with this problem.

PS : This device is also not detecting in **Windows PC**.

Comment: have you tried connecting your device as a camera?

Comment: yes i have tried that but it is not working in that case also

Comment: Have you installed the right OEM driver?

Comment: yes i have installed the right drivers

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Oppo Reno f2, found any solutions?

Comment: No unfortunately there is no solution for this problem. I tried a lot of things but none of them worked

Comment: No unfortunately there is no solution for this problem. I tried a lot of things but none of them worked